# Add bars to a plot to show averages after applying pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, pandas-groupby

I have a sample dataframe:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'cluster':['1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2','2','3','3','3'],
                 'type':['a','b','c','a','a','b','c','c','a','b','c','a']})
```

Then I plot % of type values for each cluster by using groupby:

```
pct_col = test.groupby(['cluster','type'])['type'].count()/(test.groupby('cluster').size())*100 # don't reset the index!
test = test.set_index(['cluster', 'type']) # make the same index here
test['count %'] = pct_col
test = test.reset_index() # to take the hierarchical index off again
sns.catplot(x="cluster", y="count %", hue="type", kind="bar", data=test)
```

[image]

How can I add additional three bars showing the average for each type based on the whole data set --> `test.groupby('type')['type'].count()/(len(test))*100`

Will appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(test.cluster,test.type,normalize='index',margins=True)
Out[305]: 
type            a         b         c
cluster                              
1        0.500000  0.250000  0.250000
2        0.400000  0.200000  0.400000
3        0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
All      0.416667  0.250000  0.333333

#pd.crosstab(test.cluster,test.type,normalize='index',margins=True).mul(100).stack()
```

update I thought plot is easy with `pandas`

```
pd.crosstab(test.cluster,test.type,normalize='index',margins=True).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Comment: The question is about plotting these numbers on the same plot.

Comment: @aviss check the output hehe .